# Node.js RethinkDB connection wrapper with built in retries

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote connection logic for a wrapper around RethinkDB in node.js. While it works, I know it can be cleaned up, and done in a better manner. Essentially the logic is start at the first host in `config.hosts`, if `_connect()` fails, then try the next host in the array. This continues for three times, or until `config.hosts` is empty. If `__connect()` is successful just set `rethinkdbConnection` to the returned connection object.

```
var config.hosts = ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.3'];
var rethinkdbConnection;

exports.connect = function(config, callback) {
    var rethinkdbConfig = clone(config);
    delete rethinkdbConfig.hosts;

    function _connect(callback) {
        rethinkdbConfig.host = config.hosts.shift();

        r.connect(rethinkdbConfig, function(error, connection) {
            if(error) {
                return callback(error);
            }

            return callback(null, connection);
        });
    }

    _connect(function(error, connection) {
        if(error) {
            if(!config.hosts.length) {
                return callback(error);
            }

            _connect(function(error, connection) {
                if(error) {
                    if(!config.hosts.length) {
                        return callback(error);
                    }

                    _connect(function(error, connection) {
                        if(error) {
                            return callback(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            rethinkdbConnection = connection;
            return callback();
        }
    });
};
```

What is a better way to write this?

Also it would be great instead of arbitrarily trying `_connet()` 3 times, to try as many times as the length of `config.hosts` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive promises. If promises don't exist in your platform, you could use a third party library or a polyfill to do the same thing.

```
function tryConnecting(config, remainingHosts){

    // Make a copy of hosts that we can shift off stuff. Don't modify config.
    remainingHosts = config.hosts.slice(0);

    // Promises resolve or reject only when we call resolve and recject.
    // When we see that we can still retry, we don't call either.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)){

        // Update host
        config.host = remainingHosts.shift();

        // Try connecting
        r.connect(config, function(error, connection) {

            // If it fails and we still have hosts remaining, call the function
            // again. This promise's resolve and reject will be called when that
            // call's promise resolves or rejects
            if(error && remainingHosts.length) tryConnecting(config, remainingHosts).then(resolve, reject);

            // If it's an error, and we have no more remaining hosts, we reject
            // the promise. If this call was not the first (ie. previous call
            // failed with remaining hosts), then that promise will be rejected
            // with the same values.
            else if(error && !remainingHosts.length) reject(error, null);

            // If no error, then we resolve with the connection. If this was
            // not the first call (ie. previous call failed with remaining
            // hosts) then, that promise will resolve with the same values.
            else resolve(null, connection);
        });
    });
}

exports.connect = function(config, callback) {
    tryConnecting(config, config.hosts).then(callback, callback);
};
```